# Using Vector3.Lerp to get midpoint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball and want the main camera to follow it around so I attached a script to the camera:

```
public class Tracker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;

    void Update()
    {
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, target.transform.position, .5f);
    }
}
```

Where the target is the ball gameobject.
I want the camera to have the same x and y coordinates as the ball but keep its original Z.

Not sure what to do, maybe there's a different way of approaching this?

Comment: Make a new vector3. Use the new x and y values but use the objects z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create you movement Vector3 with a constructor
for ex:

```
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(target.transform.position.x,target.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, newPos, .5f);
```

Comment: Didn't think of that, thank you!